# isLoading from useAuth0() is always false

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have a question about how isAuthenticated and isLoading works.

Im trying to redirect to login if isAuthenticated is false AND isLoading is false too, that way I know that the requests are completed.

So, Im doing

```
const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()
if (isLoading) return <Loader />
 if ((!isAuthenticated && !isLoading)|| error) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
```

...
But the login appears once FLASHING before the app finally redirects to home, because isAuthenticated is initialy false and isLoading is always false so… first goes to login and then to home page when isAuthenticated change to true.

How is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem was caused by the Auth0 Provider being outside of your BrowserRouter. This caused weird things to happen with calling history.push/history.replace.

I had a similar problem and solved it by moving my BrowserRouter inside my Auth0 Provider.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be from the `useAuth0` hook. As Pedro Porta suggested, make sure the hook is within the `BrowserRouter` parent component.

However, your current code could be cleaner. You can rewrite it like this:

```
const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()

if (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated) {
   return <Redirect to="/login" />
}
return <Loader />
```

Comment: Yes thanks for your suggestion, Im just trying, then I will clean up the code. Anyway, the isLoading from auth0 still not working :(. Not even with the Pedro porta suggestion.

Comment: @laura I think the issue is in the code. If is Login page flashes before redirection, then it could be that `isLoading` and `isAuthenticated` is initially set to `true`. Go through the logic you've set diligently.

Comment: Yes of course! But I think even the code is ugly, never should happen that isLoading and isAuthenticated were both false. And the logic on my code depends on that so... Im lost :(